# How can I debug Delphi component code in C++ Builder projects?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have a component package written in Delphi and it works fine. However, when I use the same components in C++ Builder projects they don't work fine. So, I would like to use the IDE to debug into the Delphi component code while running the C++ project. But I haven't managed to figure out how to do that.

I found some instructions, but I have only managed to get it work for the Delphi RTL code - not my own. So, I don't see the blue dots for my units, although I see it for the Delphi units.

I am compiling the packages (design time only) with dcc32 cmd line with debug information (-D+) and the C++ project with Runtime packages=false and Link with Dynamic RTL=false.

I am now generating the exe and project .obj files to the same directory where I have the .dcus:s and .objs corresponding to my components.

So, what am I missing still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this blog post
https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/mixing-delphi-and-c
From memory, the video goes into using Delphi from the C++ project.
If you add the files to the project and run the make command you should then be able to use them and debug.

Comment: "Go look at this other site to get an answer* is not acceptable here. The relevant content should be here in the answer, with the off-site link as an additional resource. Your answer has no value if that off-site link becomes invalid for any reason.

Comment: Thanks! The relevant content was that Delphi sources can be compiled in C++ projects. I had already tried that, but my project was mixed up and it just failed. I couldn't sort that out, but creating a new project helped. So I needed more confidence to try that harder. Also, my original problem that I was supposed to debug disappeared when I got his working... ;)

Comment: I still couldn't figure it out how to debug code that is compiled from C++ libraries, but I did figure out that the binary is different, if I link with libraries instead of direct to the source. So, the original problem remained unresolved, but this was good enough for me for now.